Azure AppService (Linux, Container) Memory with Deployslot
I currently build my spring boot app with the gradle bootBuildImage task, which uses the paketo buildpack by default.
An AppService on a Basic SKU with 7gb of RAM shows the following memory calculation on startup:
024-10-25T11:42:24.7155969Z Calculating JVM memory based on 5279620K available memory
2024-10-25T11:42:24.7157590Z For more information on this calculation, see https://paketo.io/docs/reference/java-reference/#memory-calculator
2024-10-25T11:42:24.7157947Z Calculated JVM Memory Configuration: -Xmx4388605K -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=184454K -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240M -Xss1M (Total Memory: 5279620K, Thread Count: 250, Loaded Class Count: 30152, Headroom: 0%)
2024-10-25T11:42:24.7261763Z Enabling Java Native Memory Tracking
2024-10-25T11:42:24.7665897Z Adding 146 container CA certificates to JVM truststore
2024-10-25T11:42:24.8033897Z Spring Cloud Bindings Enabled
2024-10-25T11:42:24.8155962Z Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -javaagent:/agents/java/applicationinsights-agent-codeless.jar -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=200M -Djava.security.properties=/layers/paketo-buildpacks_bellsoft-liberica/java-security-properties/java-security.properties -XX:+ExitOnOutOfMemoryError -Xmx4388605K -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=184454K -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240M -Xss1M -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:NativeMemoryTracking=summary -XX:+PrintNMTStatistics -Dorg.springframework.cloud.bindings.boot.enable=true
2024-10-25T11:42:25.1403899Z OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Sharing is only supported for boot loader classes because bootstrap classpath has been appended

So, out of the available 7GB of the AppService, the container gets around 5.3gb, which seems reasonable considering some overhead.
However, I plan to use on production a deployment slot for zero downtime deployments. How does this work with resources?
Has the deployment slot some fix amount of memory allocated to it? Is it 50/50 with the actual AppService? If its less, what happens when I swap?
Are buildpacks like this fitting for an AppService where also potentially multiple AppServices can run on the same AppServicePlan?
I am not sure if I should switch to a regular dockerfile and set memory limits via JAVA_TOOL_OPTS by myself.
What is best practice when running containers (with a deployment slot) on a Linux AppService?

What is the version of your App?

What do you mean by App?

Application.. what is the version of your app service?

Sorry I am not sure what you exactly mean by version of the appservice. I use a Linux AppService on Dev in the B3 SKU with 4 vCPUs and 7GB RAM.

O you are cteating app from portal.. without deploying any code?

Yes, no IaC currently. I deploy a spring boot 3.3.x container via azure devops pipelines

Paketo's Java buildpacks utilizes a tool called the memory calculator to automatically configure the memory settings for the JVM based on the environment in which it's running.
It starts by looking for cgroups/cgroups2 info, which would be available when running on most container orchestration platforms and falls back to procfs info if that's not available. It then takes the total memory available and divides that up based on typical Java memory usage patterns and some specifics that it detects about your application, like the number of class files and the presence of certain libraries. In the end, you're left with a reasonable memory configuration that works for most apps and will not cause your application to exceed the container memory limits.
The last bit is very important if you want your JVM-based application to run stably on most container orchestration platforms. If you don't get this right, your app will at some point, usually when it's most busy and so at the most inconvenient time, exceed its memory limit and be killed by the container orchestration platform. When this happens, the JVM goes away immediately (like a kill -9) and there is no crash dump or debug information to know why your app exceeded its memory limits. It is an infuriating and difficult problem to debug, one that can be completely avoided by using the memory calculator.
You might be thinking that the JVM will handle this for you, but it doesn't. It is somewhat container-aware, but it will by default, at the time I write this, overcommit different memory regions and thus allow for the potential that your application exceeds the container memory limit and is killed at a most inconvenient time. The only way presently to avoid this is to either manually configure JVM memory regions, which is error-prone and requires knowledge of JVM memory management, or use a tool like the Paketo memory calculator.
You might also be thinking that your application is special and that the memory calculator can't possibly set the memory assignments correctly for it. That's totally OK. The memory calculator will easily back off if you as the user set any of the standard JVM memory configuration flags.
This is done by setting JAVA_TOOL_OPTS and dictating how you want a particular memory region to be configured. For example, if you need more metaspace, then set JAVA_TOOL_OPTS='-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=200M (or whatever size you need), and then the memory calculator incorporates this into its calculations to ensure that you get the requested max metaspace size and also that you still do not exceed the memory limit for your container (assuming that is mathematically possible if you ask for 1G and your limit is 1G then you just don't have enough memory).
As mentioned in the documentation, you almost never want to set the max heap size manually. The memory calculator will back off if you set it manually, it ultimately respects your decision, even though it's a bad decision. The reason it's a bad decision is that by setting the max heap manually, you've taken away the memory calculator's ability to dynamically adjust the heap size to consume all of the remaining memory in your container. So if you don't get the manually set max heap size value exactly right, then you're leaving memory unused in your container (i.e. wasting $$). What's worse is when you later increase the memory size of the container, expecting it to automatically start using the larger memory footprint, but it doesn't because it's stuck to the manual value you configured (hopefully you'll figure that out quickly, and without a lot of pain).
So how do you increase the max heap? Simple. Just increase the memory in your container & restart the container. The memory calculator will dynamically adjust and provide all of the additional memory you gave the container to the JVM's available heap.

To answer your questions specifically...

How does this work with resources? Has the deployment slot some fix amount of memory allocated to it? Is it 50/50 with the actual AppService? If its less, what happens when I swap?

I don't know the Azure service you're referencing, so I can't speak to the exact behavior, but if it runs containers and exposes cgroup or cgroup2 information, then the memory calculator will know how much memory is available and it will be able to do its job just fine.
In regards to swap, my recollection is that memory and swap are different properties in the cgoup/cgroup2 metadata so any available swap will not be taken into consideration with the memory calculator's calculations. If you follow standard practices and use the memory calculator's recommendations your app should run just fine without swap, however, if swap is available it won't hurt anything.

Are buildpacks like this fitting for an AppService where also potentially multiple AppServices can run on the same AppServicePlan?

The memory calculator assumes that your Java process will be the only process running in the container. This maximizes the available memory to your application & the JVM. However, that is not always the case. Maybe your app shells out and runs some other processes or maybe you have a side car process. That is perfectly fine, you just need to tell the memory calculator about that other stuff, which you can do by setting the BPL_JVM_HEAD_ROOM env variable. This takes a percent value (i.e. from 0, the default, to 100, which wouldn't make sense) and leaves that percent of the memory out of its calculations so it's available for other applications to use.

I am not sure if I should switch to a regular dockerfile and set memory limits via JAVA_TOOL_OPTS by myself.

You shouldn't need to do this. As I mentioned above, you can always set JAVA_TOOL_OPTS settings manual,ly and the memory calculator will automatically adjust giving you the best possible memory configuration while still honoring the values you've given it.

Hey, thanks for the really detailed answer. However, I think there is a misunderstanding regarding "swap". In AzureAppservices you can provision a deployment slot, which basically is a second AppService where you can deploy to, test the new version and then swap the deploy slot with the "main" appservice for zero downtime deployments. My question is basically what happens when the "main" appservice gets 5.5gb memory (calculated by paketo), maybe the platform reserves a minor amount for the deployslot (e.g. 500mb). What happens when I do the swap? (Deploy Slot becomes the main Appservice).

For reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-staging-slots?tabs=portal. But yes, this is probably a question really specific to this azure service. However, I did not come very far with the support yet.
